# Ionic how to use buttons instead of usual ion radio and make them horizontally aligned

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, radio-button

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="gender">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="male" checked></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="female"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I want them to look as two buttons, a user can select only one button and on selection color of button will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with buttons like this

```
<div>
    <button ion-button [color]="gender == 'Male' ? 'secondary' : 'primary'" (click)="gender = 'Male'">Male</button>
    <button ion-button [color]="gender == 'Female' ? 'secondary' : 'primary'" (click)="gender = 'Female'">Female</button>
</div>
```

demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cbqd9q?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)